# "No more track names available" when using OpenSL ES

Tags: android, audio, opensl

I'm using OpenSL ES and my android app has need for multiple channels, so I create multiple player-objects (plus one player-object for each of mp3-files I need to play). This works fine for one application, but when I ran another app I've created, it will fail to play any sound and log files say

```
E/AudioFlinger(  119): no more track names available
E/AudioTrack( 6884): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
E/libOpenSLES( 6884): AudioTrack::initCheck status 4294967284
W/libOpenSLES( 6884): Leaving Object::Realize (SL_RESULT_CONTENT_UNSUPPORTED)
```

Okay, I've read that this means I'm out of free objects and I should release some objects.

However, according to http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/opensles/

> OpenSL ES for Android supports a single engine per application, and
>   up to 32 objects

So is that 32 objects per application, or is it globally 32 objects? If so, I'm forced to Destroy() (and recreate) Player-objects every time my app becomes inactive (onPause/onStop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be 32 objects per device. So it's better to `Destroy` them whenever not needed (`onStop`, `onDestroy`)